# Connecting to a WPA network in Linux with a USB dongle

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wpa, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to connect my computer to a wireless network in Linux Mint. I used the Windows Wireless Driver program to load the Windows XP drivers for my USB dongle, a Cisco / Linksys AE1200. After that step is done, I can see the wireless networks. I live in college housing, and they provide a restrictive and throttled public network that I can connect to. Unfortunately, I can't connect to their secure network which uses a WPA key.

I have no idea how to debug this problem. I've tried messing with wpa_supplicant to see what information I could learn. It appears to be timing out during authentication and trying to tell me that my PSK is wrong. The same machine running Windows 7 with the dongle connects without any problems. A netbook running Linux is able to connect fine to the network using its onboard wireless. So it seems like something is choking between Linux, ndiswrapper, and wpa_supplicant. Where should I look for the problem, and is this even something I can fix?